# How can I pass an ID from selected table row to my AJAX function that fetching data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Sorry to bother, I'm having a trouble passing and ID to my AJAX function.

I wanted to pass the ID of the selected table row to my AJAX function and use it for my query in my controller

[image: this is my table]

this is the code for my table row

```
<div class="container">

<h2 style="margin-top: 12px;" class="alert alert-success">Details</h2><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <td colspan="2">Action</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="users-crud">
      @foreach($merchants as $merchant)
      <tr id="user_id_{{ $merchant->id }}">
      <td>{{ $merchant->id}}</td>
      <td>{{ $merchant->first_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $merchant->email }}</td>
     <td><a id="getData" onClick="getData({{$merchant->id}})" class="btn btn-info">Show</a> 
     </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
      </tbody>
      </table>
      {{ $merchants->links() }}
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

upon click show ID should pass it to my AJAX function,
this is the code of the script

```
   <script type=text/javascript>
      $(document).ready(function() {
       });
    
       function getData(id){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
          $.ajax({  //create an ajax request to display.php
          type: "GET",
       url: "getproducts/",
       // dataType: 'json',
        data: {id: id}, // This will be {id: "1234"}     
        success: function (data) {
       $("#id").html(data.id);
       $("#first_name").text(data.first_name);
       }
       });
    
      };
    
    </script>
```

And ID will be use for my query in my controller, this is my controller's code, note that the number 1 in my where query is hard coded, I wanted to put the ID that I get from the selected table

```
public function getproducts()
{
    $merchants  = DB::table('merchants')
    ->select('merchants.*', 'product.product_name as product_names')
    ->join('product','product.id','=','merchants.id')
    // THE NUMBER 1 IS HARD CODED
    ->where('merchants.id', 1)
    ->paginate(8);
    return response()->json($test, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every method in a Laravel Controller can have arguments "injected" into them, including the `Request $request` variable. Add this to the top of your Controller after your `namespace` declaration:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Then modify your method:

```php
public function getproducts(Request $request) {
   ...
}
```

Then, instead of hard-coding the value `1`, you pull it from your `$request` object:

```php
->where('merchants.id', $request->input('id'))
```

The full documentation can be seen here:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#accessing-the-request

Comment: Hello sir thank you for your response, but how can i call it in my controller from my ajax function?

Comment: `$request->input('id')`, since you're sending `{id: id}` from your AJAX call, will have the value of `1234`... Is there something unclear about that? *"how can i call it in my controller"* - Call _what_? That comment doesn't make a lot of sense...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it worked!! thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me. What is the issue you are facing? But you can improve code by bit more.

```
<td><a id="getData" onClick="getData({{$merchant->id}})" class="btn btn-info">Show</a>
```

Instead you can use a global class. Also using same HTML id in a class is not good practice.

```
<td><a class="merchant_info" data-id="{{$merchant->id}}" class="btn btn-info">Show</a>
```

Now need modification to jQuery code

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.merchant_info').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");

       // Now do the Ajax Call etc

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: hello sir thank you for your response, i think the problem is in my controller, i pass the id in data: {id: id}, but i dont know how to call it in my controller